# Combine data from two collections in one query with sorting and pagination MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two collections
Property_Rent and Property_Sell because i have two sections on my app and they are separated like this so it's pretty good structure like that.
When user wants to get all properties from one user i want to be able to combine them because i want to sort and paginate.

```
  const [propertySell, propertyRent] = await Promise.all([
    Property.find({ "user._id": ObjectId(req.user.id) }),
    PropertyRent.find({ "user._id": ObjectId(req.user.id)})])


  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    propertySell,
    propertyRent
  })
```

I'm able to do like this and then i can combine them on frontend inside NgRx store but now i want to sort them, filter, paginate etc.. And i need to do that on the backend.